# RecyclerView.Adapter return null object reference inside Fragment with viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, recyclerview-layout

I am trying to create the page that have view pager with mvvm architecture.

So what i trying to do is showing the Recycler view inside the fragment of the first tab by using observable method.

But when i try to set the content is of the adapter inside my fragment i got

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.xxxx.view.adapter.FoodListAdapter.setFoodList(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
```

My FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Log.d("Food Pager", "get Item");
                FoodListFragment foodListFragment = new FoodListFragment();
                return foodListFragment;
            case 1:
                RestaurantListFragment restaurantListFragment2 = new RestaurantListFragment();
                return restaurantListFragment2;
            case 2:
                RestaurantListFragment restaurantListFragment3 = new RestaurantListFragment();
                return restaurantListFragment3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

My activity

```
private void observeViewModel(final CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel) {
        // Observe Category Data
        categoryViewModel.getCategory().observe(this, new Observer<Category>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Category category) {
                // Update UI
                if (category != null) {
                    if (category.foods != null) {
                        startFoodListFragment(category.foods);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Category Data is Null");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startFoodListFragment(List<CategoryQuery.Food> foodList) {
        Log.d("startFoodListFragment", "yolo");
        FoodListFragment foodListFragment = new FoodListFragment();
        foodListFragment.setFoodList(foodList);
    }
```

So inside my Fragment

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("Food LIst", "On create VIew");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_list, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_food_list);
        // mLoadingIndicator = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.food_list_loading_indicator);

        Integer gridColumns = 2;

        Float width = getScreenSize().get("width");

        if (width > 600) {
            gridColumns = 3;
        }

        // Create Pinterest Style RecyclerView
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(gridColumns, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Cool. it's Very easy ,but margin on my LinearLayout didn’t seem to work. So here’s a quick fix.
        SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(8);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);

        mFoodListAdapter = new FoodListAdapter(foodListAdapterOnClickHandler);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFoodListAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (mFoodList != null) {
            mFoodListAdapter.setFoodList(mFoodList);
        }
    }

    public void setFoodList(List<CategoryQuery.Food> foodList) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setFoodlist");
        if (foodList != null) {
            mFoodList = foodList;
            mFoodListAdapter.setFoodList(mFoodList);
            // mFoodListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

This is part of my adapter

```
public void setFoodList(final List<? extends CategoryQuery.Food> foodList) {
        if (this.foodList == null) {
            this.foodList = foodList;
            notifyItemRangeInserted(0, foodList.size());
        }
    }
```

This is the related Log that i got

```
D/Food Pager: get Item
D/Food LIst: On create VIew
D/startFoodListFragment: yolo
D/Food List Fragment: setFoodlist
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Then the error goes on

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.xxx.view.adapter.FoodListAdapter.setFoodList(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
```

So anyone knows why i got null, when calling `FoodListAdapter` even after i was initialise inside `onCreateView`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the log tell us?

> D/Food Pager: get Item

The `FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(int position)` was called to show a `FoodListFragment`. This usually means the `Fragment` will be added to the screen, so its `onCreateView()` should be called next. Which is actually the case:

> D/Food LIst: On create VIew

On the other hand, we have an `Observer` to listen for data changes. Every time it fires,  `startFoodListFragment()` will be called:

> D/startFoodListFragment: yolo

In this method, a *new instance of `FoodListFragment` will be created*. You try to pass the new data into it by calling `setFoodList()`

> D/Food List Fragment: setFoodlist

But since this new instance is not about to be attached to the screen, its `onCreateView()` has not been called. So its adapter has not been instantiated. That's why the app crashes:

> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

What can you do?

You should pass the data into the correct instance of `FoodListFragment`. Or simply register the `Observer` inside `FoodListFragment`. A `Fragment` is a Lifecycle Owner just like an `Activity`, so I think this approach would work best for you.

Comment: In this case, if i want to access the correct `FoodListFragment` instance, how can i do that?

Comment: @Varis Darasirikul - for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54468167/5015207) does it by keeping a List of all Fragments and reusing them. But I'd really suggest setting up the Fragment with its own ViewModel and Observer. It's a much cleaner approach

Comment: Thanks!, i already done it. By access correct instance from an activity, i have to go this way because on that activity i have 1 endpoint to send a part of data to many widget. That is why i can't observe the viewmodel inside 1 fragment.

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul - I see your point. Of course one could have both the Activity as well as the Fragment register an observer and listen to data changes. But I'm not really an architecture guru, so I'm not sure what's best. Anyway, good to hear you solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you have this method `startFoodListFragment()` which creates a fragment and calls `setFoodList()` method on it which internally sets data to adapter.

As the adapter instance is being created on `onCreateView()` lifecycle method, the adapter would not be initialized at the time of object creation. so it will be null at that time that's why it is throwing `NullPointerException`. Make sure that when you access adapter, it must be after the `onCreateView()` method is executed so that you will never get `NPE` again!